# На ruso отвечают медленно, а на enso сразу минусуют. Что мне делать?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, stackoverflow, нормы-поведения

Не могу задать этот вопрос на английском стеке, сразу закрывают. Я думаю все, даже  модераторы много раз пытались пробиться сквозь стену минусов. Но даже 
не у всех людей с большим количеством репутации это получалось. Stack Overflow стал слишком груб(я про английский). Без обид, но здесь программистов мало, и не все могут ответить. На английском же людей миллионы, отвечают очень быстро, но успеешь задать несколько вопросов, как ты уже заблокирован. Я конечно рад такому хорошему и приветливому русскому Stack Overflow, где все рассуждается по честному. Но отвечают на сложные вопросы медленно, уже забрасываешь что-нибудь, не дождавшись ответа. Но на англ. стеке какой-то ужас!
 
[image]
Что делать?
Я знаю, что не по теме, и прочее, но там сразу, мнгновенно закрывают!

Comment: Не очень понятно, в чем суть темы. У вас на EN SO 3 вопроса, все отвеченные и с нулевым рейтингом.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Посмотрите на мои удаленные ответы)))

Comment: @VerNick, для просмотра удаленных ответов нужны прямые ссылки.

Comment: На самом деле все очевидно: задавай **хорошие** вопросы, и минусов не будет.

Comment: @Grundy В том то и дело, что я не могу определиться какие хорошие.

Comment: @VerNick, для этого есть специальная страница: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) и [то же самое на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Grundy Читал уже сто раз.

Comment: @VerNick, мало просто прочитать, нужно еще и следовать указанным советам.

Comment: @VerNick А я вот с вам согласен, если честно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Видите ли, на английском stack overflow действительно более строгие порядки, но давайте лучше поговорим не о них, а о вас. Вот вы спрашиваете, а что с этим делать.

А вы поплавайте пока на отмели. У нас тут намного более спокойные воды, попривыкнете - а потом уже понимая брод сунетесь на большой so.

Прямо скажем, у вас пока и на ru so есть сложности. Несколько раз вы получали question ban, вы не понимаете, как отличить хорошие вопросы от плохого, вы пока не очень хорошо понимаете, как качественно делать проверки. Поэтому идти сразу на en so можно только из чистой воды мазохизма.

Могу порекомендовать две конкретные вещи:

- старайтесь ничего не делать, если вы не уверены на 200% в том, что именно это нужно делать. Здорово, если у вас хватает репутации на очереди проверок - но лучше сначала почитайте историю проверок, обращая внимание на те, которые делают постоянные проверяющие, их нет уж и много.
- чаще спрашивайте совета у более опытных коллег. Если вам непонятно, почему был закрыт тот или иной вопрос - лучше спросите. Вам станет понятно, а потом когда попадётся вопрос за закрытие - сможете поступить по аналогии. Да и местные порядки станут яснее: когда ваш вопрос заминусуют и закроют - глядишь станет понятее, почему.

Это всё не о ваших вопросах было, это всё про "общественную активность". А про ваши собственные вопрос - хотите - можете продолжать спрашивать, хотите - можете пока сделать паузу.

На stackoverflow (и там и тут) любят конкретные вопросы, когда человек не просто спрашивает "как сделать сайт/бота/мобильное приложение", а спрашивает по конкретной технологии. И там и тут если вы сумбурно выражаете свои мысли вам могут конечно уточнить, поправить, попросить переформулировать - но большинство либо пройдёт мимо (потому что никто никому не обязан), либо влепит воспитательный минус или голос за закрытие.

Вообще, весь флоу устроен таким образом, что вас несёт по течению от момента, когда вы задаёте вопрос и до момента, когда вы получите ответ -- а двигаться против течения очень непросто, а порой и откровенно больно.

Вообще же, если какой-то один мегауниверсальный совет, то он тоже достаточно прост: чем меньше вы доставляете проблем окружающим - тем легче вам самому живётся. Дайте простой понятный вопрос, на вас заработают галку, десяток репутации, немного повысят самооценку и пойдут дальше.

Если же вы ведёте себя как-то вне шаблона - то вас приходится модерировать, тратить время (которое можно было бы потратить на более понятные вопросы). Думаете, айтишникам нравится вся эта модерация, чреватая конфликтами, обидами, ссорами и так далее? Поэтому просто старайтесь плыть по течению, развиваться самому и не сильно доставать окружающих.

Хорошо, что вы пытаетесь прокачаться в программировании, но нужно понимать, что никто не обязан отвечать на те вопросы, которые вам нужны здесь и сейчас. Получили ответ - ПОВЕЗЛО, а не получили - идите и работайте сами. Как ни странно, но если у вас самостоятельно получается пробиться сквозь сложный вопрос - это и удовольствие приносит больше (по крайней мере, люди с такой мотивацией чаще становятся лучшими программистами) и запоминается лучше, а готовый ответ, который нам достался бесплатно мы ценим мало и осмысливаем хуже.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо.