# Могу ли я "переезжать" с одного аккаунта на другой?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, репутация, профиль-участника, блокировка

Меня уже заблокировали и на enSO, и на M&TV SO, так что мне не очень весело(на последнем меня заблокировали за несколько дней, хотя у меня вопрос с рейтингом 16!). Везде <strike>сидят заумные минусовщики</strike> мне не везет. Я подумал о том чтобы переехать и снова попытаться поискать счастье, но одна вещь которую сложно передать — это репутация. Мне пришла идея передать ее по конкурсу, но этим я обижу участников которые скорее всего напишут большой ответ с надеждой выиграть конкурс, победитель которого уже определен. Так, я съехал с темы. Могу ли я вообще переезжать, то есть удалить этот аккаунт и остаться на новом. Если можно, то как?

Comment: [Связанный вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8085/) (не дубликат)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Создание аккаунтов для избегания блокировок, конкурсы для передачи репутации своему "клону" — всё это чистые нарушения правил.

---

А вообще, ваш ход мыслей неверный. Если вы не понимаете, что же именно вас привело к ситуации с блокировками, то новый аккаунт "без криминального прошлого" вас не спасёт. Что если опять вернётесь к такой же ситуации? Ещё раз новый аккаунт и так до бесконечности?

Поэтому советую не беспокоиться и не унывать по поводу случившегося, не принимайте всё на личный счёт, постарайтесь просто понять какие именно ваши действия приводят к таким ситуациям, какие именно правила нарушаются. Ваши блокировки не являются клеймом на всю жизнь. Достаточно всего лишь сделать выводы, как не попадать в такие же ситуации и всё тогда нормализуется. И не понадобиться изобретать способы изображать для окружающих фиктивное "чистое" прошлое.

Answer (score 9):

Про переезды Вадим всё правильно написал. Вас поймают и влепят заслуженный бан. Не делайте так.

Посмотрел на enSO и M&TV: банов у вас там нет. Возможно, вам заблокировали возможность задавать новые вопросы. Это делает система, автоматически и без вмешательства людей. И это временно, как любой бан. Причина — много вопросов в минусе. Вот они на киношном сайте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы снова задавать новые вопросы на тех сайтах и больше не получать блокировку, сделайте вот что:

1. Отредактируйте свои уже опубликованные вопросы. Просто чтобы они выглядели лучше. Вот я вам один вопрос [отредактировал](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51749227/revisions) для примера.
2. Почитайте справку на каждом сайте. Поймите, что там уместно спрашивать, а что — нет, как задавать хорошие вопросы.

   - На киношном сайте ваш вопрос получил -5 за то, что он субъективный.
   - В вопросах на SO вы сначала кидаете кусок кода, а потом текст. Так читателю непонятно, лучше сначала текст пишите.
3. Если сомневаетесь, сначала спрашивайте на Мете: «А можно ли тут задавать вот такой вопрос?» или «Как мне улучшить мои вопросы?». Последний вопрос вообще волшебный, он открывает сердца самых чёрствых вахтёров. Вот сравните:

   > Q: За что вы мне понаставили минусов?
   >   A: За то, что ты справку не читаешь, на тебе ещё минусов!
   >
   > Q: Как мне задавать вопросы получше?
   >   A: Хм, давай покажу и объясню.
4. Если опытный участник сайта редактирует ваш вопрос, не откатывайте правку, [как вот здесь](https://movies.stackexchange.com/posts/93603/revisions). Так вы мешаете человеку вам помочь и обнуляете его работу. Вместо этого постарайтесь понять суть правки и поблагодарите редактора в комментариях через `@name`.

Comment: Я ж и говорю — блокировка, а не бан. Про опытного участника — он до этого почти всю суть вопроса оставил, и мне не понравилось. За ответ - спасибо, буду пытаться.

Comment: @VerNick бан тоже по-официальному называется блокировкой. Просто есть ещё «частичные» блокировки, например «задавать вопросы не чаще чем раз в день».

Comment: Как-то странно получается. Когда вы отредактировали, вопрос сразу плюсов получил. Когда я отредактировал, молчание.

Comment: @VerNick наверное, потому что я хорошо редактирую технические тексты. :) Это моя основная работа, я технический писатель.

Comment: @VerNick конкретно что поправил: английскую грамматику, пояснил что именно не нашёл и где, сокращение HTML написал заглавными.

Comment: Ну ладно, буду переправлять, пока не получится :)